# Add metadata for images as key/value pair?

Tags: metadata

I am trying to add metadata to images, and I want it as key/value pairs. I know about the possibility to add keywords. But they are just a list of words. I would like to be able to add the metadata as pairs, like Product=Apple. Is this possible? If so, what type of metadata would it be (xmp, exif...), and how do I add it (e.g. in Adobe Bridge)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be [XMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform) as it allows for specification of custom "namespaces/schemas", though it is XML-based. Full documentation is on [Adobe website](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/xmp.html). In fact [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24416653/is-it-possible-to-create-a-custom-namespace-tag-in-xmp-dublin-core-metadata) shows you can do it with free ExifTool.